# Generated file is still locked

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, memorystream

I am using OpenXML SDK to generate and save a word document.

I am using a "Using" Block to create and dispose of the memory stream, and word document object when they are finished. However when trying to open to file i get the error that the file is still in use by another process.
Looking at Resource Monitor i have been able to find that it is my c# application still keeping it open.
When i close my application i can use the file

I have the following code.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create Stream
    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Create Document
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
        {
            // Add a main document part. 
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

            // Create the document structure and add some text.
            mainPart.Document = new Document();
            Body docBody = new Body();
            mainPart.Document.Append(docBody);
            wordDocument.SaveAs(@"E:\Report\word.docx");
            // Add your docx content here
            wordDocument.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Am i correct in understanding that

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
```

should dispose of the MemoryStream when the block finishes, and therefore allow the file to be used by another process?

Thanks

Comment: The `MemoryStream` is not locking a file. Since it is a **memory** (not file) stream.

Comment: MemoryStream is a *memory* stream. It's a stream API on top of a `byte[]` array.  It has nothing to do with files. If you have a locked file, it's because something keeps that file open. BTW you don't need that MemoryStream if you intend to save the document to a disk, you could have used the file path in the document constructor and remove `SaveAs`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for letting me know this, turns out the SaveAs was causing the problem, so replacing the MemoryStream would solve the problem too ( while apparently being better code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.saveas?view=openxml-2.8.1#DocumentFormat_OpenXml_Packaging_OpenXmlPackage_SaveAs_System_String_) returns a *new* package object that represents the package stored in that file. You need to `Close` that package too.

```
wordDocument.SaveAs(@"E:\Report\word.docx").Close();
```